# Any ORM for ionic, angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, orm, capacitor

Is there any recommendation for ORM that can be used with Ionic 6 & Angular?

If yes, can you provide guide to connect the ORM with Ionic 6? I tried `typeorm` with `capacitor-community/sqlite` but it's not working somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the database from your frontend is not possible. Browsers don't support the protocols required to access the database. You need a REST api or similar server technique to perform database operations. This REST api would then run on a server of yours and you can communicate with it with HTTP.

On a high level the architecture would then look something like this:

[image]

I can recommnend [NestJs](https://nestjs.com/) as a REST api framework. It is build up similar to angular and support tpypeorm without an issue. Checkout their webpage, they offer nice tutorials to build up a REST api to your needs